# Customization of the frame's contents

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to set an image on left of an itemize using this code. How to customize there position? I'm just trying to put them on top of my frame after the header.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A.
    \item B.
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `t` in the optional argument for `frame` to get top alignment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A.
    \item B.
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answers are always perfectly done. Thank you very much for being here !